# Excel VBA Not Equal not working

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

Hi have found a macro on another forum that solved my problem: It copies cells from Sheet 2 matching Sheet 1.

Sub Compare()

```
Dim WS As Worksheet
Set WS = Sheets("Master")

Dim RowsMaster As Integer, Rows2 As Integer
Dim Rows3 As Integer
RowsMaster = WS.Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Rows2 = Worksheets(2).Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Rows3 = WS.Cells(WS.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
' Get the number of used rows for each sheet
ScreenUpdating = False
With Worksheets(2)
    For i = 2 To Rows2
    ' Loop through Sheet 2
        For j = 2 To RowsMaster
        ' Loop through the Master sheet
            'below line checks for matches to variable number, file and field
            If .Cells(i, 1) = WS.Cells(j, 1) And .Cells(i, 3) = WS.Cells(j, 3) And .Cells(i, 4) = WS.Cells(j, 4) Then
            ' If a match is found:
                WS.Cells(j, 6) = .Cells(i, 1)
                  WS.Cells(j, 7) = .Cells(i, 2)
                    WS.Cells(j, 8) = .Cells(i, 3)
                      WS.Cells(j, 9) = .Cells(i, 4)

                ' above copies in the data
                 Exit For
                ' No point in continuing the search for that company

            ElseIf j = RowsMaster Then
            ' If we got to the end of the Master sheet
            ' and haven't found a company match

                Rows3 = Rows3 + 1
                ' Increment the number of rows
                For k = 1 To 4
                'For l = 2 To 4 ' Change 3 to however many fields Sheet2 has

                    WS.Cells(Rows3, 11) = .Cells(i, k)
                    ' Copy the data from Sheet2 in on the bottom row of Master
                Next
            End If

        Next j
    Next i
End With
ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This code matches up the values from sheet2 to master. The ones that dont match end up in cell K6 only - what I need is for the ones that done match to start in column K (4 columns of date K:N) and then each one on a new row.

Can anyone help me with this - been working on it for 2 days and cant get it working!

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you set breakpoints and use the `Locals` window to examine the status of your variables as the code executes.  That should point you in the right direction.

Comment: fwiw, the way you have it set up all three comparisons have to fail. If you want it to fail on only one mismatch then change the two `And` to `Or`. Additionally, you are exiting the loop after getting your first 'hit'